# Google App Engine: action on datastore changed

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm building an GAE powered application which is able to store a dataset. External applications are able to access this dataset using Google Cloud Endpoints.

When external applications edit this dataset(PUT POST DELETE) I want to run a script on my GAE. I could do this by adding this code to the PUT/POST/DELETE api methods; example:

```
/**
 * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
 * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
 * It uses HTTP POST method.
 *
 * @param sensor the entity to be inserted.
 * @return The inserted entity.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "insertSensor")
public Sensor insertSensor(Sensor sensor) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        if (containsSensor(sensor)) {
            throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        mgr.makePersistent(sensor);
        ########RUN SCRIPT HERE########
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return sensor;
}
```

But I was wondering if GAE offers better solutions regarding this kind of problems?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the Datastore PrePut & PostPut callbacks ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/callbacks))?

Comment: Yes indeed. Although they don't offer callbacks for PostGET, and both PrePOST and PostPOST?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question: these callbacks are for datastore _put_ and _get_ operations. Is that not what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do additional processing or actions when you receive a request on a route handler or on an Endpoints API function, [I'd recommend strongly that you look into Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) to solve that problem. This enables you to perform the background processing/hooks that you define, while also keeping the latency on your requests low, making sure the client has the data they need undisturbed by your app needing to do extra processing unrelated to serving their request.